# Making a Cassandra Connection inside Hadoop MapReduce Task

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

I am successfully using the [DataStax Java Driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) to access Cassandra inside my Java code just before I start a MapReduce Job.

```java
  cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
```

However I am needing to check additional information to decide on a per record basis how to reduce the record. If I attempt to use the same code inside a Hadoop Reducer class it fails to connect with the error:

```
INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : 
attempt_201310280851_0012_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: 
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1 ([/127.0.0.1] 
Unexpected error during transport initialization 
(com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1] Error writing)))
     at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:186)
     at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:81)
     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:662)
     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.access$100(Cluster.java:604)
     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:69)
     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:96)
     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:585)
```

The MapReduce input and output will successfully read and write to Cassandra. As I mentioned I can connect before I run the job so I do not think it is an issue with the Cassandra server.

Comment: Any other errors? Is this a complete exception? Any errors on the server side?

Comment: No that was the only error, it did not happen when the job tracker was set to local. That said I have moved to using PIG instead now.

Comment: Is it a single node cluster? If it has more nodes, then your reducer might be run on some other node. Are you sure you can connect to localhost from *all* of the nodes?

Comment: It was under a single node cluster although still happened either way